# Margin auto does not work

Tags: html, css, margin

I am not able to center the banner img. I want it to adjust size when the window size changes. (to keep it in proper proportions on tablets/smartphones)

The image max size is 918px but margin auto does not seems to work. Does anybody have any ideas what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

original page: http://www.syntra-limburg.be/nieuws/nieuwe-gecertificeerde-opleidingen-2014-2015

```
<style type="text/css">
#banner img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<div class="container-12">
    <div class="grid-12" id="banner"><img alt="" src="/sites/files/content/slides/20140616-gecertificeerde-opleidingen-2014.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you inspect the `img`, you'll see that `display:block` **isn't** being applied. Add it and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: block` to `img`

```
#banner img 
{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Strange, now it works and before it did not. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The banner image is getting stretchable, it doesnt look good when in smaller screen size. Remove it from the inline styles.

And try this

```
#banner img{
    width: 800px;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
#banner { text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the width to 100% and it works.

Comment: Image hasn't same width as its parent, he can't use that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: No, `img` has width 800px, container is bigger > you deform an image. Additionaly, with `width: 100%` no `margin: auto` is required.

Comment: Than it should be wrapped in media-queries for tablets/smartphones.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But the question is not about media queries, responsive design etc., but the problem is with desktop. And there is a solution only `margin: auto` without `width: 100%` as I wrote in my answer above.

Comment: It is  about media-queries: `"I want it to adjust size when the window size changes. (to keep it in proper proportions on tablets/smartphones)"`

Comment: Ah, sorry. Mea culpa.